# How to Add certain results of columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a basic Query to pull the sum of Services from a table:

```
Select Service, Sum(Qty_Sold) as Total
From Services
Where Service in ('1','2','3','4')
Group By Service
```

Output:

```
Service     Total
   1          8
   2          9
   3          22
   4          11
```

I Recently added a new service, but I want to add a new service, which will be "7" and have it added to the "4" service So - My data would be:

```
Service    Total
   1          8
   2          9
   3          22
   4          11
   7          1
```

But I'd like my output to be:

```
Service    Total
   1          8
   2          9
   3          22
   4          12
```

I've tried:

```
Select * from 
(
Select Case When Service = '7' then '4' Else Service, Sum(Qty_Sold) as Total
From Services
Where Service in ('1','2','3','4','7')
Group By Service)
Group By Services, Total
```

This still doesn't get me the total I need, It just List's '4' Twice.  How can I get it to Combine 4 and 7 to display what I want?

Comment: you should have copied what @juergen gave you.. you did not include the value 7 in your where clause `Where Service in ('1','2','3','4')` needs to be `Where Service in ('1','2','3','4','7')`

Comment: I already had that in there.  It lists "7" but as 4. So output is 4 - 11 4 - 1  It just replaces 7  with 4 - doesn't add it together in his or mine.

Comment: i've tested the answer that was deleted and it works fine.. here is a working demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cedf86/1

Comment: When I run it - I am told that "Service is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."  If I add "service" after the case when - the query runs, but changes 7 to 4 and lists 4 twice.

Comment: can you post the actual query you're trying to run that is giving you that error?  your `I've tried:` query is not even valid since you're missing the `end` in the case expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT
    CombinedService, SUM(Total) AS CombinedTotal
FROM
    (   SELECT 
            CASE 
                WHEN Service = '7' THEN '4'
                ELSE Service
            END AS CombinedService,
            SUM(Qty_Sold) AS Total
        FROM
            Services
        WHERE
            Service IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '7')
        GROUP BY
            Service
    ) cs
GROUP BY
    CombinedService
```

Comment: This is perfect, I completely blanked on the "Sum(Total)".  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than messing with complicated WHERE clauses, can you create a new table of 'ServiceDescriptors':

ServiceID  ServiceDesc

1           1

2           2

3           3

4           4

7           4

Then, just sum based on ServiceDesc.  As you add new ServiceIDs, you'll appreciate this solution even more.

HTH, Jim

Comment: OK, plan B.  I think the issue is that your outer SELECT * isn't summing the Total, it is just reporting what is returned in inner SELECT.  So, force it to sum:  SELECT Service, Sum(Total) from ...

Comment: Here's the full statement:

Select Service, Sum(Total) from 
(
Select Case When Service = '7' then '4' Else Service, Sum(Qty_Sold) as Total
From Services
Where Service in ('1','2','3','4','7')
Group By Service)
Group By Services, Total

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a CTE to join to the Services table.

```
WITH cte(origService, newService) AS (

    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (7, 4)) t(o, n)
)
SELECT newService AS Service, sum(Qty_Sold) AS Total
FROM cte
JOIN Services s ON s.Service = cte.origService
GROUP BY newService
```